# ¿Cómo poner un gif dentro de un botón en C# (winforms)?

Tags: c#, windows-forms, .net, dotnetcore

Estoy intentando hacer un botón que cuando el mouse entra cambia el fondo por un gif.
[image: Llamas]

La imagen cambia correctamente, pero el gif no se reproduce; Investigando un poco encontré un [código de como hacerlo](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0d9e790e-6816-40e7-96fe-bbf333a4abc0/show-animated-gif-in-datagridview?forum=winformsdatacontrols), pero parece que no reproduce el gif.

> Post data: Estoy intentando hacerlo todo a mano en Visual Code, podría hacerlo en Visual Studio, pero quiero aprender como se hacen las cosas a mano para entender como funcionan las cosas

Mi idea original era ponerle encima del botón un gif de fuego, pero apenas estoy empezando en esto así que decidí hacer lo mas simple

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Winform_test_no_editor {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        // Objetos iniciales
        public Label label1;
        public Panel panel;
        public Button boton_llamas;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            // Label
            this.label1 = new Label(){
                TabIndex = 0,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                Size = new Size(0, 100),
                Name = "label1",
                Text = "Mi boton flameante",
                Padding = new Padding(10),
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font(
                    "Agency FB",
                    24F,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    ((byte)(1))
                )
            };
            // Creamos el panel donde estará el boton
            this.panel = new Panel(){
                AutoSize = false,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                TabIndex = 0,
                Size = new Size(0, 60)
            };
            // Crear un botón en llamas 
            this.boton_llamas = new Button(){
                Name = "boton_flameante",
                Text = "Fire!",
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Size = new Size(150, 100),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font(
                    "Arial",
                    18F,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    ((byte)(1))
                )
            };
            this.boton_llamas.Location = new Point(){
                X = (this.panel.Width - this.boton_llamas.Width)/2,
                Y = (this.panel.Height - this.boton_llamas.Height)/2
            };
            this.boton_llamas.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(this.Flamas);
            // Añadimos todo al formulario
            this.panel.Controls.Add(this.boton_llamas);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        }
        bool animating = false; 
        void PintarBoton(object sender, PaintEventArgs e){
            // Inicar la animacion
            this.AnimarImagen();
            // Actualizar frames
            ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();
        }
        void AnimarImagen(){
            if(!this.animating){
                ImageAnimator.Animate(
                    this.boton_llamas.BackgroundImage, 
                    new EventHandler(this.Actualizar)
                );
                this.animating = true;
            }
        }
        void Actualizar(object o, EventArgs e){
            this.boton_llamas.Invalidate();
        }
        private void Flamas(object sender, EventArgs e){
            // Le añadidmos la imagen
            this.boton_llamas.BackgroundImage = 
                Image.FromFile(@".\fire-51.gif");
            this.boton_llamas.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(this.PintarBoton);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Pon `BackGroundImageLayout` a `Center`.
2. Pon la propiedad `Image` al boton de tu gif

Comment: Prueba estos 2 metodos, juntos y por separado. Al parecer chrome tiene un error, por eso hay que agregar el center, y backgroundImage no reproduce gifs, Image si

Comment: @Excorpion ¿Que le pongo en "Image" al gif? En el evento de MoseEnter cambio el BackgroundImage

Comment: Lo segundo, encontre que backgroundImage no reproduce gifs, pero prueba, no es respuesta esto, es solo algo de ayuda

Comment: @Excorpion Vale, gracias igualmente

Comment: @Excorpion Wow, funcionó xd. Ahora si gracias

Comment: De nada bro! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Parece ser que BackgroundImage no reproduce GIFs, pero la propiedad Image sí.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Winform_test_no_editor {
    public partial class Form1 : Form {
        // Objetos iniciales
        public Label label1;
        public Panel panel;
        public Button boton_llamas;
        public Form1() {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            // Label
            this.label1 = new Label(){
                TabIndex = 0,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
                Size = new Size(0, 100),
                Name = "label1",
                Text = "Mi boton flameante",
                Padding = new Padding(10),
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font(
                    "Agency FB",
                    24F,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    ((byte)(1))
                )
            };
            // Creamos el panel donde estará el boton
            this.panel = new Panel(){
                AutoSize = false,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                TabIndex = 0,
                Size = new Size(0, 60)
            };
            // Crear un botón en llamas 
            this.boton_llamas = new Button(){
                Name = "boton_flameante",
                Text = "Fire!",
                BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Center,
                Anchor = AnchorStyles.None,
                Size = new Size(150, 100),
                UseVisualStyleBackColor = true,
                Font = new System.Drawing.Font(
                    "Arial",
                    18F,
                    System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                    System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point,
                    ((byte)(1))
                )
            };
            this.boton_llamas.Location = new Point(){
                X = (this.panel.Width - this.boton_llamas.Width)/2,
                Y = (this.panel.Height - this.boton_llamas.Height)/2
            };
            this.boton_llamas.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(this.Flamas);
            // Añadimos todo al formulario
            this.panel.Controls.Add(this.boton_llamas);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel);
            this.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        }
        private void Flamas(object sender, EventArgs e){
            // Le añadidmos la imagen
            this.boton_llamas.Image = 
                Image.FromFile(@".\fire-51.gif");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por que pones lo mismo que le dije al OP?